# Zapier: RingCentral Trigger + Search Salesforce for similar phone # + if/no then

Tags: salesforce, zapier, ringcentral

Ok, here is what I'm trying to do. When we receive a new RingCentral Voicemail, I want Zap to search Salesforce to see if the From phone number exists in a lead or contact. If it doesn't, I then want RingCentral to send a text message to the phone number that left a voicemail. Any ideas on how to go about this?

I have RingCentral Voicemail as the trigger. I can then set up Salesforce to search specific fields to see if this number exists. But, there aren't any options to continue if the phone number doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

David here, from the Zapier Platform team.

That's (mostly) not possible at this time, but that's a great feature request! The best way to get this heard is writing into our support at `contact@zapier.com` and letting them know. They'll be able to collect info from you and let you know if that gets released.

---

I say mostly above because it's not possible on an actual "search" step. You *can* write a custom app that behaves differently, but writing a custom app for Salesforce would be quite an undertaking. I don't personally recommend it.